# pthread_join receiving results from function in a array

Tags: c, pthreads, pthread-join

I'm working with pthreads in C and have run into problems(again).
I am trying to send results as an array of a function to my main thread.

This code finds the largest value for each worker(1worker/row) and saves the indexes for that value. So far so good.
I will explain my problem below this function. This code does what i want.

```
for (i = first; i <= last; i++){
    for (j = 0; j < size; j++){
    total += matrix[i][j];
        if(matrix[i][j] > biggest){
    biggest = matrix[i][j]; 
    x=i;
    y=j;
    maxValueResult[1]=i;
    maxValueResult[2]=j;
    }else if(matrix[i][j] < smallest){  
    smallest = matrix[i][j];
            indexes[2]=i;
            indexes[3]=j;   
}
} 
}      
    maxValueResult[0]=biggest;
    maxValueResult[1]=x;
    maxValueResult[2]=y;
printf("Results: maxValue: %d cord[%d,%d]\n",maxValueResult[0],maxValueResult[1],maxValueResult[2]);

return *maxValueResult;
```

My problem is when i recive the results in pthread_join only maxValueResult[0] works, from maxValueResult[1] and maxValueResult[2] i only get addresses or something.
before: " return *maxValueResult;" all three values are correct, looking something like this: "Results: maxValue: 95 cord[3,3]"

Here is where i call pthread_join:

```
for(l=0;l<numWorkers;l++){
pthread_join(workerid[l], &maxValue);
temp[l] = maxValue[0];
if(maxValue[0]<temp[1]){
    maxValue[0] = temp[1];
    xCORD = maxValue[1];
    yCORD = maxValue[2];
}
}
printf("Results: maxValue: %d cord[%d,%d]\n",maxValue[0],xCORD,yCORD);
```

That prints this:
"Results: maxValue: 95 cord[0,1629976061]", where 95 is correct but not the other two.
What can I do to fix this?
As you probably can see from my code, im not very experienced.

EDIT: I forgot to tell about the warnings, i get a couple! Unfortunatly they are in swedish, but i post them here anyway:
"$ gcc -o sumb matrixSumB.c
matrixSumB.c: In funkcion "main":
matrixSumB.c:120:1: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘pthread_join’ from incompatible pointer type
/usr/include/pthread.h:144:5: note: expected ‘void **’ but argument is of type ‘int * (*)[3]’
matrixSumB.c: In function "Worker":
matrixSumB.c:172:1: warning: return makes pointer from integer without a cast. 
"

Kind Regards Leo

Comment: Where are you creating maxValueResult? Is it a auto variable inside the thread? It may be getting destroyed when the thread exits.

Comment: You should probably get compilation warnings with the code in the question. The statement `return *maxValueResult;` returns only the first value in the `maxValueResult` array, and not a pointer to the array. And of course, returning pointers to local variables is a big no-no.

Comment: Im creating it in the beginning of the function where it is used.

Comment: How are you creating it? By doing a malloc or on the stack? Can you post that piece of code?

Comment: Yes, i did get warnings, i editet my first post and added them there!

Comment: I create my threads with:   for (l = 0; l < numWorkers; l++){
    pthread_create(&workerid[l], &attr, Worker, (void *) l);

 }

Comment: Regarding the warning messages, could you please change your language settings from Swedish to English, so more people can understand what they mean?

Comment: I'm working on that, will edit first post as soon as im done.

Comment: Warnings is in english now.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
return maxValueResult[0];
return maxValueResult[1];
return maxValueResult[2];
```

Comment: I did now, didnt make any difference.